Weight issue when streaming MP4 in Django when rewinding
I encountered a problem when rewinding a video that was streaming from another service.
When rewinding on this service, everything works well and mp4 files are rewinded quickly.
another service
In my case, when using StreamingHttpResponse, the video starts loading again from the very beginning to the point where I rewinded.
my streaming service
Here is my Python code:
from django.http import StreamingHttpResponse
import requests


def stream_file(request):
    video_url = "https://stream.voidboost.cc/bc1442336011256eb53bad59edce97f4:2024051610:SDM0cmRNelBMMHhqQitwTnlHSVVuUUVUOVhjRVJwZjJrV3RYMjRRMzZDcXR2SUtwbVp4T3BJMFJFUFNCRVNFdy9tZEJJdllFUzU1NklwMFpld0NIdFhqZ3FZQTdMR2oxR1dJNVplY3dpZXc9/4/4/1/2/3/v022a.mp4"
    response = requests.get(video_url, stream=True)

    def file_generator():
        for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=8192):
            yield chunk

    headers = {
        'Content-Length': response.headers.get('Content-Length'),
        'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes'
    }

    return StreamingHttpResponse(file_generator(), content_type=response.headers.get('Content-Type'), headers=headers)

I have no experience with this.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
